# Open a webpage from console (C#) after 10 seconds

Tags: c#

I'm writing a console application in C#. How can I open a webpage after 10 seconds? I already found something like

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.stackoverflow.com")
```

but how can I add a timer?

Comment: You need to add timer it is avaialbe in toolbox.

Comment: Put a Thread.Sleep(10000) before the shown line. Or better explain what you really need.

Comment: Look at the `System.Threading.Timer` class

Comment: Just use [Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ah1h85ch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or look at [Task.Delay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh139096%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method if Thread.Sleep is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose from the below options depending on the application:

1. [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx)
2. [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx)
3. [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx)

For example:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep((int)System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10).TotalMilliseconds);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open this page every 10 seconds try this

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.Interval = 10000;
timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
timer.Start();

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
    timer.Stop();   //If you don't want to show page every 10 seconds stop the timer once it has shown the page.
}
```

And if you want it to only show page once than you can stop the timer by using `Stop()` method of timer class.

Comment: I assume you talk about the Winforms Timer. That one simply won't work in a console app.

Comment: Yes assuming that windows forms is being used.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to open url within C# using 
`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start` I am suggesting you to read [this](http://www.devtoolshed.com/content/launch-url-default-browser-using-c), I copy-paste the code posted in that webpage, in case the link will be broken in same day:

```
public void OpenLink(string sUrl)
{
    try
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(sUrl);
    }
    catch(Exception exc1)
    {
        // System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception is a known exception that occurs when Firefox is default browser.  
        // It actually opens the browser but STILL throws this exception so we can just ignore it.  If not this exception,
        // then attempt to open the URL in IE instead.
        if (exc1.GetType().ToString() != "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception")
        {
            // sometimes throws exception so we have to just ignore
            // this is a common .NET bug that no one online really has a great reason for so now we just need to try to open
            // the URL using IE if we can.
            try
            {
                System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("IExplore.exe", sUrl);
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);
                startInfo = null;
            }
            catch (Exception exc2)
            {
                // still nothing we can do so just show the error to the user here.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Regarding the suspended execution please use [`Task.Delay`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh139096%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
  var t = Task.Run(async delegate
          {
             await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
             return System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
          });

  // Here you can do whatever you want without waiting to that Task t finishes.

  t.Wait();// that's is a barrier and the code after t.Wait() will be executed only after t had returned.
  Console.WriteLine("Task returned with process {0}, t.Result); // in case System.Diagnostics.Process.Start fails t.Result should be null
```